# How to enable swapping db connection parameters with EclipseLink/JPA

Tags: jpa, dynamic, connection, persistence, eclipselink

We have projects of various types such as a backend java process and a front-end tomcat app that currently use EclipseLink/JPA and persistence.xml to get the db connection info.  Is there a way to allow for those parameters to be dynamically changed, say in the case that the backend db has been moved to another server.  The persistence.xml is packaged in the jar and is not directly modifiable.  I see various threads that talk about dynamic persistence but nothing on this particular theme.  Is there somewhere that documents this specifically with any examples?

Thanks

Comment: is it ok to restart the webserver for this?

Answer (score 2):

If your persistence context is application-managed (i.e. you use `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName)` to obtain it), you can override properties from `persistence.xml` by passing your custom properties via `createEntityManagerFactory(persistenceUnitName, properties)`.

Comment: Would this allow the writing of those new parameters to the persistence unit so that they become the defaults?

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is put the JDBC connection information in the application server instead of the persistence.xml file.

So, setup your persistence.xml file like this.

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JPATest" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyDBDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>...</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Then configure your application server to have a database connection named jdbc/MyDBDS.  You can then update the connection information whenever you need to without changing the persistence.xml file.